# How to plot lines in matlab on the .fig image with rho and theta

Tags: matlab

I want to plot lines with theta and rho data on the '.fig' format image.
The image is an ellipse that made by this code. :

```
xRadius = 3 + (10-3).*rand(1,1);% horizontal radius
yRadius = 3 + (10-3).*rand(1,1);% vertical radius
x0=0;
y0=0;
t=-pi:0.01:pi;
x=x0+xRadius*cos(t);
y=y0+yRadius*sin(t);

img = plot(x,y,'LineWidth',1);
```

And the output I want is if I input rho and theta data in the function, its output are lines on the ellipse image. Its shape have to be like a radial shape but don't have to cross the center of ellipse. How can I do?

[Output that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVMI2.png)

Comment: What do rho and theta represent? Are that the axes? If so, which one is the horizontal?

Comment: You should add the function which processes your variables `rho` and `theta`. Additionally you should also explain us what exactly your problem is or in other words why you fail to plot the lines. Right now your question is not clear and it is difficult to help you, for more information see [ask]. It might be that your question is related to [plot line with theat and rho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655745/how-to-plot-line-in-matlab-with-theta-rho-data?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot line in matlab with theta/rho data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655745/how-to-plot-line-in-matlab-with-theta-rho-data)